# ASP.Net MVC Web API WebRole and Controller appear to be in different processes/domains?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static

I have a small REST application I am writing for deployment into Azure. Im using the MVC WebAPI libs to do so.

The WebRole is being deployed as a CloudService, but I don't think that is an important factor to the question (but I could be wrong).

The REST service has some dependencies on an (internal) 3rd party library, that require my WebRole to be a subclass of a RoleEntryPoint defined in the library. As part of that base class's OnStart method, it initializes a **static** Configuration class with various configuration information the service needs (connection strings, certificates, etc). I have confirmed via debugging that the static class is populated correctly.

(Note the **static** part above, its important)

Later (as measured by noticing that the breakpoints get hit after the webrole initialization), in my Controller (subclass of ApiController) for the REST service, I am attempting to retrieve some information from the Configuration class - which is now magically uninitialized.

Is the controller running in a different process/domain than the webrole class? Can I make it not be? (Is there some other reason I would be getting a different copy of the static class?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the controller running in a different process/domain than the
>   webrole class?

Yes, Azure Runtime uses WaIISHost, and ASP.NEt uses a different worker process.

> Can I make it not be?

I dont think so. Simply use Application_Start() in Global.asax to initialize your static content.